# issue with iframe in android

Tags: android, cordova, iframe

Hi i have used iframe in my android phonegap app.i set the width and height and iframe is scrolling.But the webpage inside the iframe is disabled ie. i cant able to type anything in the webpage textboxes.

If i set the scrolling="no",then iframe is not getting scrolled.But i can able to type in the textboxes.

Here is my code:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="200px" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I can able to scroll the webpage in iframe and also should able to type in textbox.Please help me to solve this problem.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

check this once and use it in your onCreate method:

```
Webview.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    Webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                        v.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried your code and app force close and showing runtime exception,Unable to start activity.